# arrayfire with python freeze

Tags: python, freeze, arrayfire

I have just downloaded Arrayfire library from acclereyes. Arrayfire is a CUDA based library and i am using it from python.I tried to run the simplest possible code in python:

```
import arrayfire as af
a=af.randu(5)
```

the prompt hangs and my cpu usage is about 50%( I have a dual core cpu). 
same thing happens when i run the examples provided.The only way to stop this is to end the process from process manager.What has gone wrong? Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: You could put a bit more effort and at least format your question properly... Using the code formatting would certainly help.

Comment: The issue is cross posted in our forums. Vote to close. http://forums.accelereyes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3547&p=11139#p11139

Comment: What model of NVIDIA GPU are you using?